# Naming CSV files after converting from XLSX(with mutliple sheets) as a batch r

Tags: r, xlsx

```
library(xlsx)
lapply(files.to.read, function(f) {
df = read.xlsx(f, sheetName = 'Sheet8')
write.csv(df, gsub("xlsx", "csv", f), row.names=FALSE) 
     })
```

I am converting xlsx to csv and want to

- add the sheet name to the end of each filename
- create multiple csv for sheets8:10 for each file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

**code**

```
files <-  list.files(path = "./", pattern = "*.xlsx$", recursive = FALSE, full.names = TRUE)
sheet_to_read <- c( 8, 9, 10 )

library( readxl )

for( excelsheet in files) {
  for (sheet in sheet_to_read) {
     temp <- read_excel( path = excelsheet, sheet = sheet)
     write.csv( temp, file = paste0( "./", gsub("./", "", excelsheet), "-sheet", sheet,".csv") )
  }
}
```

**result**

[image]